# Error: no se admite para la deserialización de una matriz. en Json Console Aplicattion

Tags: c#, json

Estoy consumiendo un WebService desde una aplicación de consola. El problema que tengo es cuando recibo el Json y lo intento deserializar, ya que me devuelve el error :    "no se admite para la deserialización de una matriz".

[image: Error]

La estructura del Json es la siguiente:

```
[{
    "id": "19454",
    "serial1": "4634170894",
    "fecha1": "12-03-2018 00:19",
    "sis_datetime": "2018-10-26 17:17:06",
    "mileage": "None",
    "voltage": "14.804",
    "engine_operation": "1.0",
    "lat": "-90.9160305",
    "lon": "14.2409938",
    "sis_packat_zike": "820",
    "params": "{'custom1': 123.36666666661733, 'posinfo': {'c': 187, 'h': 132.46, 'lon': 14.2409938, 'sc': 10, 's': 0, 'lat': -90.9160305}, 'voltage': 14.804, 'report_type': 2, 'engine operation': 1.0, 'custom': 187.0, 'accum_9': 158, 'accum_8': 0, 'accum_3': 0, 'accum_2': 12251, 'accum_1': 4178, 'accum_0': 14804, 'accum_7': 0, 'accum_6': 0, 'accum_5': 0, 'accum_4': 0, 'event_index': 13, 'engine rpm': 1625.000000001248, 'event_code': 1, 'hdop': 1.2, 'unit_status': 0, 'host': '', 'accum_14': 0, 'seq_num': 42885, 'iridium': 0, 'rssi': -93, 'accum_15': 0, 'avl_inputs': 63, 'accum_13': 158, 'accum_12': 0, 'accum_11': 0, 'accum_10': 0}"
}]
```

El código es el siguiente:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Web;
using System.Net;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Web.Script.Serialization;



namespace WsMotobombas
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            string myConnectionString = "";

            var url ="";

            using (var response = webrequest.GetResponse())
            using (var reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
            {
                var result = reader.ReadToEnd();

                string jsonstring = result;

                var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
                //Encabezado FldEncabezado = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<Encabezado>(jsonstring);
                Encabezado FldEncabezado = serializer.Deserialize<Encabezado>(jsonstring);
                using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(myConnectionString))
                {
                    conn.Open();

                    foreach (var Registro in FldEncabezado.Items)
                    {
                        if (InsertData(conn, Registro))
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine(Registro.serial1 + " insertado Correctamente");
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("Error : " + Registro.serial1 + " Registr no insertado");
                        }
                    }
                }
                Console.Read();

            }
        }



        public class Registro
        {
            public int id { get; set; }
            public int serial1 { get; set; }
            public DateTime fecha1 { get; set; }
            public DateTime sis_datetime { get; set; }
            public char mileage { get; set; }
            public char voltage { get; set; }
            public char engine_operation { get; set; }
            public char lat { get; set; }
            public char lon { get; set; }
            public char sis_packat_zike { get; set; }
            public char paramsi { get; set; }
        }


        public class Encabezado
        {
            public List<Registro> Items { get; set; }

        }

        static bool InsertData(SqlConnection conn, Registro Lectura)
        {
            try
            {
                string xSql = @"INSERT INTO dbo.TblLecturas( Serial1 ,fecha1 ,sis_datetime ,mileage ,voltage ,engine_operation ,lat ,lon ,sis_packat_zike)";
                using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(xSql, conn))
                {
                    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Serial1", Lectura.serial1));
                    //cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@fecha1", Lectura.fecha1));
                    //cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@sis_datetime", Lectura.sis_datetime));
                    //cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@mileage", Lectura.mileage));
                    //cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@voltage", Lectura.voltage));
                    //cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@engine_operation", Lectura.engine_operation));
                    //cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@lat", Lectura.lat));
                    //cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@lon", Lectura.lon));
                    //cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@sis_packat_zike", Lectura.sis_packat_zike));
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }
                return true;
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Si alguien puede ayudarme, muchas gracias.

Comment: Estas intentando deserializar `params` como char? Podrías explicar porque usas `char` para `lat` `lon` etc?

Comment: No solo `params` tiene varios con char, adicional la clase Encabezado tiene una propiedad llamada Items que en el json no esta.

Comment: Hola @JuanSalvadorPortugal lo intenté arreglando los tipos de datos, pero persiste el problema.

Comment: Hola @OrlandoDeLaRosa me podrías indicar como debe ser correctamente? gracias.

Comment: Las propiedades de tu json, todas son cadenas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Primero pasa a string todos los char de la clase `Registro`

```
public class Registro
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public int serial1 { get; set; }
    public DateTime fecha1 { get; set; }
    public DateTime sis_datetime { get; set; }
    public string mileage { get; set; }
    public string voltage { get; set; }
    public string engine_operation { get; set; }
    public string lat { get; set; }
    public string lon { get; set; }
    public string sis_packat_zike { get; set; }
    public string paramsi { get; set; }
}
```

Pd: Si te da problema de conversion entonces debas pasar `id y serial1` a un `string`

---

## Ahora para deserializar el json a un objeto tienes dos opciones:

***Opcion 1***: Cuando vayas a deserializar el json, primero obtienes en listado de `Registro` y despues se los asignas a tu clase `Encabezado`

```
List<Registro> listRegistro = serializer.Deserialize<List<Registro>>(jsonstring);
Encabezado FldEncabezado = new Encabezado();
FldEncabezado.Items = listRegistro;
```

***Opcion 2***: Que el json tenga el siguiente formato:

```
{
   "Items":[
      {
         "id":"19454",
         "serial1":"4634170894",
         "fecha1":"12-03-2018 00:19",
         "sis_datetime":"2018-10-26 17:17:06",
         "mileage":"None",
         "voltage":"14.804",
         "engine_operation":"1.0",
         "lat":"-90.9160305",
         "lon":"14.2409938",
         "sis_packat_zike":"820",
         "params":"{'custom1': 123.36666666661733, 'posinfo': {'c': 187, 'h': 132.46, 'lon': 14.2409938, 'sc': 10, 's': 0, 'lat': -90.9160305}, 'voltage': 14.804, 'report_type': 2, 'engine operation': 1.0, 'custom': 187.0, 'accum_9': 158, 'accum_8': 0, 'accum_3': 0, 'accum_2': 12251, 'accum_1': 4178, 'accum_0': 14804, 'accum_7': 0, 'accum_6': 0, 'accum_5': 0, 'accum_4': 0, 'event_index': 13, 'engine rpm': 1625.000000001248, 'event_code': 1, 'hdop': 1.2, 'unit_status': 0, 'host': '', 'accum_14': 0, 'seq_num': 42885, 'iridium': 0, 'rssi': -93, 'accum_15': 0, 'avl_inputs': 63, 'accum_13': 158, 'accum_12': 0, 'accum_11': 0, 'accum_10': 0}"
      }
   ]
}
```

De esta forma solo aplicas la deserializacion como lo estas haciendo:

```
Encabezado FldEncabezado = serializer.Deserialize<Encabezado>(jsonstring);
```